# Retrieving data from firebase database into multiple textviews with custom adapter showing no errors/displaying nothing?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-adapter

Been trying to load all the data from a firebase database into four different textviews with a custom adapter. Getting it to work with one textview was rather straight forward.

Making it work with a custom adapter proved much more difficult. The code runs, but nothing is showing in the interface and can't figure our why because it's not generating any errors either. Any ideas as to why this is not generating errors or not displaying data?

Here is the structure:
[image]

Record Model:

```
public class Record {
    public String clicked;
    public String date;
    public String diff;
    public String sync;
    public String uid;

    public Record(){

    }

    public String getClicked() {
        return clicked;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public String getDiff() {
        return diff;
    }
    public String getSync() {
        return sync;
    }
    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }


    public void setClicked(String clicked){
        this.clicked = clicked;
    }
    public void setDate(String date){
        this.date = date;
    }
    public void setDiff(String diff){
        this.diff = diff;
    }
    public void setSync(String time){
        this.sync = sync;
    }
    public void setUid(String uid){
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public Record(String sync, String clicked, String diff, String date, String uid) {
        this.clicked = clicked;
        this.date = date;
        this.diff = diff;
        this.sync = sync;
        this.uid = uid;
    }
```

CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context c;
    ArrayList<Record> records;
    public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Record> records) {
        this.c = c;
        this.records = records;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return records.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return records.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.list_adapter_view,parent,false);
        }
        TextView timeTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texttime);
        TextView clickedTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textclick);
        TextView diffTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textdiff);
        TextView dateTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textdate);


        final Record s= (Record) this.getItem(position);
        timeTxt.setText(s.getSync());
        clickedTxt.setText(s.getClicked());
        diffTxt.setText(s.getDiff());
        dateTxt.setText(s.getDate());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;  
    private String mUserId;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    DatabaseReference db;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();

    static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile2);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


        if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
            loadLogInView();
        } else {
            mUserId = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mUserId).child("records");
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, retrieve());
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Record> retrieve()
    {
        db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        return records;
    }

    private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            records.clear();
            Record record= dataSnapshot.getValue(Record.class);
            records.add(record);

        }
    }
```

activity_user_profile2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:paddingTop="5sp">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

list_adapter_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/texttime"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textclick"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textdiff"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textdate"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is not any ViewHolder in your Adapter class. Add a ViewHolder in your adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a couple of lines in the Activity class were not in the right place. Here's the working solution.

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    private String mUserId;


    CustomAdapter adapter;
    DatabaseReference db;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();



    static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile2);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


        if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
            loadLogInView();
        } else {
            mUserId = mFirebaseUser.getUid();

            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mUserId).child("records");


            retrieve();




        }

    }


    public ArrayList<Record> retrieve()
    {


        db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        return records;
    }

    private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {




            Record record= dataSnapshot.getValue(Record.class);

            records.add(record);



        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,records);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



    private void loadLogInView() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
            loadLogInView();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```